# La signification et l'usage de la construction « Monsieur le » ou « Madame la » + nom

Tags: expressions, sens, usage, politesse

J'ai entendu souvent cette construction : « Monsieur le » ou « Madame la » + nom.

La première fois que j'ai entendu cette expression, c'était dans une chanson de Jacques Brel (*Les Bourgeois*).  [On peut l'écouter ici](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAATPjCRjS4) ; l'expression est utilisée à 2m14. (Je sais que dans cette chanson c'est un peu de la moquerie).

**Les paroles:**

> Et c'est en sortant vers minuit, *Monsieur le Commissaire*,
>
> Que tous les soirs, de chez la Montalant

**Je m'intéresse à l'expression en tant que formule de politesse.**

Je l'ai utilisée en m'adressant à un professeur, par exemple :

> « *Bonjour Monsieur le Professeur* »

**Je voudrais connaitre la signification de cette expression, savoir comment on l'utilise, et les contextes dans lesquelles elle est appropriée (avec des exemples, si possible).**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On utilise cette expression quand on s'adresse à quelqu'un en utilisant son titre plutôt que son nom. C'est d'un registre formel, puisqu'on insiste sur le titre (la profession de l'interlocuteur), au lieu de son nom.

Par exemple :

> Monsieur le Député
>   Madame la Ministre
>   Monseigneur l'Évèque

Comment: Pourriez-vous donner des exemples contextuels?

Comment: Note : parfois dans l'armée "Monsieur le" est réduit en "Mon" : "Monsieur le capitaine" devient "Mon capitaine". (au masculin seulement)

Comment: @PatrickSebastien Si vous écrivez un courrier officiel il est d'usage d'apostropher ainsi. ("Veuillez agréer, Monsieur le Proviseur, mes excuses les plus sincères", "Veuillez trouvez ci-joint, Madame le Juge, les enregistrements téléphoniques demandés"). Notez d'ailleurs qu'on peut parfois trouver "Madame le [...]".